# node-sass não é reconhecido como um comando interno

Tags: node.js, sass

Estou tentando criar um comando para **compilar os scss em css** mais facilmente.

[Segui esse tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275)

Instalei o nodejs, npm e o node-sass

Entrei no meu projeto e rodei o comando

> npm init

Meu package.json está assim:

```
{
"name": "piattino",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Documenação do site piattivo.com.br",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "scss": "node-sass -watch scss -o css"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

após isso rodei o comando:

> npm run scss

e então recebo o seguinte erro:

```
> piattino@1.0.0 scss C:\Users\bruno\projetos\piattino
> node-sass -watch scss -o css

'node-sass' n▒o ▒ reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper▒vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! piattino@1.0.0 scss: `node-sass -watch scss -o css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the piattino@1.0.0 scss script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean 
to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11- 
01T15_04_15_598Z-debug.log
```

**utilizo o windows 7 64bits
node v10.13.0
npm 6.4.1**

Comment: Acredito eu que provavelmente você esqueceu de instalar o node-sass. Utilize o comando `npm i node-sass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa instalar o node-sass globalmente:

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

Ou adicioná-lo em seu `package.json` como uma dependência:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
},
```

E então executar:

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Seu script também está incompleto, deveria ser assim:

```
"scss": "node-sass -watch -include-path scss -o css"
```

O `-include-path` define a pasta onde os arquivos `scss` estão, e o `-o` é a pasta de saída de seu arquivo compilado.

[Referência](https://css-tricks.com/why-npm-scripts/)

Comment: path.js:39
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('path', 'string', path);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)

Comment: Tentei instalando o node-sass globalmente e após tentar npm run scss deu esse erro acima. Da outra forma, após rodar 'npm install --save-dev  node-sass' apareceu um erro enorme que não consigo colar aqui mas o inicio dele é esse: Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/win32-x64-64_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/win32-x64-64_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Comment: Tenta novamente agora, editei a resposta com uma versão mais recente do pacote como dependência.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda mas deu o mesmo erro. no caso esse primeiro comentário que fiz.

Comment: Editada novamente, seu script no `package.json` está incompleto, percebi só agr qd tentei executar ele.

Comment: fiz as edições no script e depois de rodar 'npm run scss' o processo fica pendurado, tem ideia do porque?

Comment: Ele vai ficar observando mudanças nos arquivos `scss`, ou seja, toda vez que você fizer alguma modificação e salvar o arquivo, ele vai ser compilado automaticamente.

Comment: SHOW! muito obrigado agora deu certinho!

Answer (score -1):

node-sass para rodar no windows precisa de alguns componentes C++, instale esse cara: https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=48145 e veja se resolve.

Comment: valeu Felipe, instalei aqui mas não surtiu efeito